# Conjecture: $\pi\le\sum_{cyc}\operatorname{arcsec}(f(a,b,c))\le3\pi/2$, where $f(a,b,c)=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2-a^2b^2c^2}{2ab(1-c^2)}$ and $a,b,c>\sqrt{3}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, inverse, noneuclidean-geometry

I have the following suspicion connected with non-euclidean geometry:

Let $a,b,c>\sqrt{3}$, and 
$$
f\left(a,b,c\right)=\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}-c^{2}-\left(abc\right)^{2}}{2ab\left(1-c^{2}\right)}.
$$
Is it true, that 
$$
\pi\leq\text{arcsec}\left(f\left(a,b,c\right)\right)+\text{arcsec}\left(f\left(b,c,a\right)\right)+\text{arcsec}\left(f\left(c,a,b\right)\right)\leq\frac{3\pi}{2},
$$
 where $\text{arcsec}\left(x\right)$ is the inverse
function of $\text{sec}\left(x\right)$?

Comment: Before jumping-in to (dis)proving someone's conjecture, I like to know something about its motivation. How did you come about this "suspicion"? Why the restriction to values strictly greater than $\sqrt{3}$? How many examples have you investigated? What's special about the cases that give the extreme values in the target inequality? ... Also, please explain how this is related to non-Euclidean geometry. (Do you mean *spherical*? *hyperbolic*? *both*?) Seeing the geometric connections may provide insights into an approach to (dis)proof.

Comment: You are  absolutely right. To be honest, it's not even my own question, I have just tried to help someone...I will modify the question as soon as possible.